# xinput trackpad settings

Tags: touchpad

I am trying to disable palm detection or the disabling of the trackpad while using the keyboard.  It makes gaming impossible if you use a touchpad to do so.  I have found the setting to disable the feature i want removed but i can't seem to make it stay as default.

`xinput set-prop 12 299 0` i achieved the setting i would like.

`⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ reserved Pineapple 2.4G Optical Mouse     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam [2 MP Macro]                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
jeff@jeff-HP-EliteBook-8540p:~$ xinput list-props 12
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (142):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (293): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (294): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (295):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (296):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (297):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (298):   0
    libinput Accel Speed (276): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (277): 0.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (281):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (282):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (260): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (261):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (262):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (283): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (284): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (285):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (286):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (287):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (299):    0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (300):    1
    Device Node (263):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (264):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (292):   <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (265):    1`

As you can see, 299 and 300 are similar but 300 says default.  I am getting an error when trying to change 300.

`sudo xinput set-prop 12 300 0
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20`
  Is there any way around this or is there anything i can add to set this at startup?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why 299 is accepted but 300 isn't, but I think I can answer the second part of your question.

To set the value at startup, try adding the command to `~/.bash_profile` (create the file if it doesn't exist). Then, log out and log back in. This file is executed each time you log in. See [.bash_profile vs .bashrc](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. That will work perfectly. Much appreciated.